# How do i tell postman to scan a response for a number greater than 0?

Tags: api, postman

I have a script set up here

```
// the condition check
if (pm.response.json().totalPages === "1") {
    
    then change the method
    pm.variables.set("method", "POST")

    //call the same request again using setNExtRequest
    // pm.info.reqeustName gives current request's name
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.send)
```

how do i set it so that it runs when totalpages is greater than 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know data type of `totalPages` so I provide 2 solution for 2 cases:

-If `totalPages` is string:

```
if (parseInt(pm.response.json().totalPages) > 0)
```

-If `totalPages` is number:

```
if (pm.response.json().totalPages > 0)
```

Comment: Its a variable that is given in the response, ``` {
    "from": 1,
    "to": 0,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "total": 0,
    "totalPages": 0,
    "queryTime": "0.074",
    "totalTime": "0.074",
    "partial": false, ```

Comment: `"totalPages": 0` --> number, you can go with the second solution.